# need help in patch operations > Convert to Binary

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I want to send image to aws api gateway in base64, hence i went through some articles where it was necessary to perform patch operations to covert the image to binary. (https://medium.com/@adil/how-to-send-an-image-as-a-response-via-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-3820f3d4b6c8)

But after thoroughly going through the instructions and trying to apply them

chiragMacBook:new chirag912$ aws apigateway update-integration-response \

> --rest-api-id q1205tf9ok \
>   --resource-id t4ssj5 \
>   --http-method GET \
>   --status-code 200 \
>   -- patch-operations '[{"op":"replace","path":"/contentHandling","value": "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"}]'

I came across this error.

```
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the UpdateIntegrationResponse operation: Invalid Method identifier specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already figure this out yourself. But this error usually happens when you try to update integration response for a http method which doesn't exist.

So verify if there is a GET method defined. One common scenario could be that you might have defined a Proxy with ANY method and you are trying to update with GET which would result with the same error message.